# Make Page Content 100% Height of Document - Painful Issue

Tags: html, css

I am working on the second version of my new web app Trekeffect and I want my interface content to be 100% of the pages height, but I just can't seem to figure it out.  I make the HTML, body and all other parent elements 100% height, but no matter what I do the height never fills the document.

This screenshot shows my issue:
[image]

You can view the issue by visiting: http://dev.trekeffect.com/home
and then by clicking on any of the cities listed: Example: Anchorage, Alaska

I've played around in Firebug and no matter what I do I can't get this working.  Please help!

Answer (score 3):

It is because of this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.three_col .right {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Remove those, and your problem is solved!

The reason this is causing a problem, is because CSS sets the body to a height of 100% of the available screen space.. Therefore any content below this is considered overflow.

---

[image]

Comment: That actually doesn't fully solve it.  If I do your suggestion and my content is small or my browser height is large then the content does not take up 100% of the screen anymore.  How can I do this?

Comment: This is what it looks like with your suggestion on my screen: http://awesomescreenshot.com/06f1o82g27

Comment: Alright, there is another instance where a height of 100% is specified.. remove that also, see my updated answer.. let me know if this works.

Comment: Even with your updated answer this still does not work.  Any other suggestions? I even tried removing height on all other child elements, but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: Before attempting anything else.. does it work if you specify a definite pixel height? For instance, 5000px.. ? If that doesn't work, I have no idea.. However, if it does work, that is the solution. Since all pages have different heights, I would then write some javascript to dynamically change the set pixel height.

Comment: If I specify a defined pixel height on .content_wrap of 5000px then the page is really long and the contents of the page do not fill in the 5000px.  This does not seem to work.  I have also tried min-height: 100% and that didn't have any effect.